# What is text pattern in Ephemerol report

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

What is text pattern in Ephemerol report?

[Ephemerol Url](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pivotal-Field-Engineering/ephemerol/)

Answer (score 0):

Text pattern is some thing which is already specified as part of the default-rulebase.yml rules. This is used to get report when the code is scanned using Ephemerol. Also, the refactor rating is not explained nicely in the github or as part of documentation.

[Rules Link](https://github.com/vmware-archive/ephemerol/blob/master/ephemerol/static/default-rulebase.yml)